# NodeJS,I can see the data in Request Payload on client side but I cannot see the data in request object on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send data from client to server nodeJS. But data is not seen on server. What am I missing?
**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var testField = $('#testField').text();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on("click",function() {
        if ((!$('#testField').val())) {
            $('#error').text("Please enter Test");
        } else {
            $('#error').hide();
            console.log ("Ajax call");          
            console.log ("Inner Ajax call");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/testUrl',
                    data: testField,
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log ('Response Success:', result);
                    },
                    failure: function(result) {
                        console.log ('Response Failue:', result);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<div id="testId">Test:<input type="text" name="testField" id="testField">     </div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="code"></div>
<div id="button"><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"></div>    
</html>
```

When I enter value in testField and press enter, it should be received on server.js
Below is the code for server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var qs = require('querystring');

function send404Response (response) {
    console.log ("send404Response");
    response.writeHead(404, {"Context-Type" : "text\plain"});
    response.write("Error 404: Page not found");
    response.end();
}

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log ("onRequest");
    if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
        console.log ("onRequest - GET - Home page");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type" : "text\plain"});
        fs.createReadStream ('./index.html').pipe(response);
    } else if ((request.type == 'POST' || request.method == 'POST') && (request.url == '/testUrl')) {
        console.log ("onRequest - POST - testUrl - " + request.data);   //request.data is undefined - how to receive data.
        response.end();
    } else {
        send404Response(response);
    }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running");
```

request.data is undefined as mentioned in the comment section of above code. I tried visualising the request object via node-inspector. But I don't see the data sent through client to server. Please comment what am I missing.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate question, refer answer below

`function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var jsonString = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            jsonString += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
        });
    }
}`

stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: It's not working. I don't see data coming to server side. Is it because I am not submitting form. <br> How to do ajax call, if I submit form in above example?

Comment: I am pretty confident that Data is not coming from client side to server. So, delegate req.on('data', doesn't work. Am I not submitting data through AJAX call correctly?